# PDF Handler : content-disposition filename

Tags: handler, filenames, ashx, content-disposition, save-as

I am outputting a PDF file in a Web browser (IE8) `HttpContext.Response.writefile(fileName)` and it works great. When I try to save the file, it will give me the name of the ashx handler as a default. I would like to actually pass the real name.

I tried to add header information as follow:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
```

And it works but I do not want the user to have to choose between open and save, i want the file to open normally and if the user chooses to save it then the dialog would give him/her the default filename.

I tried also:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
```

Or just, like [Scott Hanselman suggested in his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheContentDispositionSagaControllingTheSuggestedFileNameInTheBrowsersSaveAsDialog.aspx).

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
```

None of those work for me. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See test cases at http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilenamepdf - it seems that this is simply a missing feature in IE.

Comment: THank you very much Julian, now it make sense.

Answer (score 9):

I also came across this problem.
What helped me was to also set the contenttype to `application/pdf` (instead of `application/x-pdf`, which is outdated)

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"Report.pdf\"");
```

Answer (score 4):

In case of INLINE, it seems that Internet explorer is using the last parameter in the URL to build the filename.
For example if your url is http://doc.com/131231231
IE will prompt you to save the file as 131231231.pdf
If you need a filename for example foo_131231231.pdf 
you can hack the IE by using this url: http://doc.com/foo_131231231
You may suffer to change your app a bit to expect such ugly parameter, but at the end your app
will work as you expect.