# Content-Disposition inline filename issue with IE

Tags: response-headers

I am displaying a pdf in browser with inline from API using an aspx page.

While saving the pdf using Chrome/Firefox, takes the filename from 
`header("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=xyz.pdf")`

But while saving the pdf using IE it does not reads the filename from 
`header("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=xyz.pdf")`. 
instead it takes the aspx name.

**Technical details**

I have an xyz.aspx page.
The xyz.aspx page will invoke an API for a document.
Then the downloaded document from API will transferred to browser with inline to display the pdf document.
Am setting the response header as below and writing the file bytes.

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + Name + "\"");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

- Issue:

  While saving the opened pdf in IE it takes xyz.aspx instead of the name from header.
- Requirement:

  While saving the pdf using IE, it need to save with the name of pdf.

I googled so much, as every one tells its IE behavior. I hope some one knows a solution.

**Note:** I have to display the pdf in browser and then save. Not to download using "attachment"

Answer (score 6):

It is true some versions of IE can't handle `("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=...")`

This is because `filename=...` was originally intended for the attachment disposition. Not all browser-based PDF viewers can handle it.

The only solution I see is to allow access via a different url.
Suppose you have a route to the pdf like: `/pdf/view`. If you change it to `/pdf/view/filename` and you configure your application to handle this route in the same way as `/pdf/view` your problem is solved.

You can also re-write the download url on the webserver.
Depending on your webserver you have various ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I have also tried with all kind of headers and methods.

In the end, my solution was

```
    private FileResult ReturnStreamAsPdf(string fileName, Stream stream)
    {
        ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Inline = true  // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
        };
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
    }
```

and the Route Attribute on the method:

```
    [Route("api/getpdfticket/{ticketnumber}")]        
    public async Task<FileResult> GetPdfTicket(string ticketnumber)
```

And the href:
href="@($"/api/getpdfticket/{product.TicketNumber}.pdf")"

It seems like Microsloft is still inventing their own standards:
http://test.greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilenamepdf

[PDF Handler : content-disposition filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818732/pdf-handler-content-disposition-filename)

Comment: This works, adding `response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");` worked for me. Thanks.