# Page title and filename not working for PDF viewer from file handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, handler, pdf-viewer

I'm unable to get the Filename and Page title for my pdf viewer using asp.net handler.

I've added the required header for HTTPS Response, still no luck.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

I'm getting
[image]

Response Header is as below

[image]

I'm Expecting below

[image]

It would be a great help if someone provides a valid solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us **all** of the response headers from Chrome Dev Tools (for that request).

Comment: @mjwills I've updated the Response Header. thanks.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260027/34092 work?

Comment: @mjwills No, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's pulling that ShowHandler.aspx from the last segment of the url. If this is set up as an IHttpHandler and defined in the system.webServer/handlers section of the web.config, you can add a wildcard in the web.config. For example, if you have `<add name="ShowHandler" path="ImageHandler/ShowHandler.ashx"` then you can change it to `<add name="ShowHandler" path="ImageHandler/ShowHandler.ashx/*"` and change your url to `http://localhost:444/ImageHandler/ShowHandler.ashx/PowerPoint%20Presentation`

That will make the last segment of the url "PowerPoint Presentation", so that will be the title of the page.