# Save as of pdf in IE doesn't save in the same name as filename

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsp, internet-explorer, activex

I have the jsp file below:

```
byte[] file=null;
    String ctype ="application/pdf";
    RispostaPdf risposta = (RispostaPdf) session.getAttribute(Costanti.ATTRIBUTE_FILE_PDF);
    String docName = risposta.nomeFile;
    response.setContentType("" + ctype + "; name=\"" + docName + "\"");
    //response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + docName + "\"");
    file = risposta.modulo;
    try {
        OutputStream outStrm = response.getOutputStream();
        outStrm.write(file);
        outStrm.flush();
        outStrm.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //response.flushBuffer();
    session.removeAttribute(Costanti.ATTRIBUTE_FILE_PDF);
```

to open a pdf doc in a new tab. 
When i save a pdf from chrome is saved with the correct name (docName):

```
filename=\"" + docName +
```

[image: Chrome saved]
[image: Chrome named file]

In IE the last version (11/10/9) is saved as downloadServletName.pdf:
[image: IE saved]
[image: IE named file]

Anyone know how can i change the saved file name as "filename=\"" + docName" in IE?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36314312/1427878) in the duplicate they had success by setting `Content-Type: application/pdf`. In your code, you seem to be appending `; name=...` after that, possible that this messes things up, so try and remove that.

Comment: Is the same result removing '; name=....' ;(